# How to make a link button contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html

On my website, I have a link using `role=button` with Bootstrap's `btn btn-primary`. When I try to assign the `contenteditable` attribute to the button, it does not work as expected and does not allow me to edit it.

---

Things I have tried : 

Disable dragging for link button

Make link button focused after having `contenteditable` set.

Remove all links from the button

Comment: It would be helpful if someone were to explain the downvotes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button id="editBtn" type="button">Click to edit me</button>
```

JQuery:

```
 $('#editBtn').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
       //$(this).focus();
       return;
   });

   $('#editBtn').on('focus', function(e){
       console.log("blurred...");
       $(this).attr('contenteditable','false');  
   });
```

JS:

```
document.getElementsById("editBtn").contentEditable = "true";
```

or

```
 document.getElementsById("editBtn").setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
```

Comment: is it possible to do so without jquery?

Comment: you want only JS?

Comment: Try with:
document.getElementsById("your_button_id").contentEditable = "true";
or
document.getElementsById("your_button_id").setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");  (I edit my reply with the new js)
Hope it can help you

Comment: Not what I was looking for but i will mark it as correct anyway. What I actually meant was that the cotenteditable tag has weird selections. Check my profile for a new question containing more details.

Comment: Ok I will check